# Imagick PDF first site

Tags: php, imagick

If i upload a pdf file with more than 1 page it will show the last page. What should i change in coding to show only the first page?
Here is the code i using to convert.

```
$impdf = new imagick( DATA_SERVER_PATH."/uploads/".$this->uploadFileDirectory.$itemID."/".$_POST['main_file'] )';
$impdf->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$impdf->writeImage(DATA_SERVER_PATH."/uploads/".$this->uploadFileDirectory.$itemID."/preview.jpg");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$impdf = new imagick( DATA_SERVER_PATH."/uploads/".$this->uploadFileDirectory.$itemID."/".$_POST['main_file']."[0]" );
$impdf->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$impdf->writeImage(DATA_SERVER_PATH."/uploads/".$this->uploadFileDirectory.$itemID."/preview.jpg");
```

Add [0] at the end of your filename, [0] is the pagenumber, so [4] will use page 5.

More readable example:

```
$file = 'filename.pdf['.$pagenumber.']';
$image = new Imagick($file);
$image->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
$image->writeImage('imagefilename.jpg');
```